# Is there a way to download all your contributions?

Tags: support, feature-request, data-dump, export

Suppose I want to download all my questions and answers, e.g., as separate latex files. Is there a way to do this automatically? For example, [this can be done on Facebook](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000707.htm) and [on Google](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3024190?hl=en). There are many good reasons a user might want to do this, e.g., to create a book of open problems. If this is currently not possible, how difficult would it be to add such a feature?

Of course, the slow way is to open every question/answer, click "edit", and copy and paste. But that will take many hours. Also, I learned that if you deleted a question then you cannot "edit" it, so you have to first undelete, then grab the text, then re-delete. Also, I learned that you can't delete more than 5 things in one day. Thought I'd record that observation in case it helps any future user.

Comment: Probably it is worth checking out the suggestions provided in previous discussions on this topic - you can easily find several such posts.
On [math.meta.se]: [How do I know I won't lose all my work in math.SE?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9148) (and other [questions linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/9148)).
On [meta.se]: [Dump of my own Stack Exchange content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269804) (and [other questions linked there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/269804)),

Comment: It is much easier to use SEDE for this - but since you mention editing, you don't have to edit the post to get to the source; you can get it through the [revision history](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/revision-history/info), too. (So it would not be necessary to undelete and delete a question only to get to the source.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, actually, this was very easy. Thanks to Martin for the links. I have created my first data explorer query and it does what I wanted. Now I have a CSV file with everything I've ever written on MathOverflow. Very easy to extract from there into a latex file if I wanted to.

Here's the query: https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1816844/get-all-questions-and-comments-from-a-given-user

In the spirit of "teach a person to fish..." I will try to solve future "Can I get X data" myself before posting on meta.

Comment: Probably it is worth mentioning that SEDE query returns [at most 50000 results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269063). But even most prolific users have much less [posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1580473/users-with-most-posts-questions-answers) and [comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1798655/users-with-most-comments). So this isn't really a problem here on MO.

Comment: On [so] there is [one user](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1580473/users-with-most-posts-questions-answers) over 50k posts and [several users](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1798655/users-with-most-comments) over 50k comments - such users would have to download their contributions from SEDE in several parts.

Comment: And since in the question you have mentioned deleted posts too, probably it is worth explicitly pointing out that deleted posts aren't available in SEDE. (There is a table PostsWithDeleted, but it contains only some data for deleted posts, body isn't one of them.)

Answer (score 4):

There is already [a fine answer](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/5858) - this is just a minor addition. Some people might prefer Markdown for the posts rather than HTML. The other query uses `Body` from the `Posts` table - this contains HTML. Markdown can be obtained using the `PostHistory` table.

- Here is a query which [returns Markdown for a single post](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1816895/markdown-for-a-specific-post?id=23478).
- Here you can get Markdown for posts of a specific user: [only questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1816894/markdown-for-posts-by-a-specific-user?userid=8250&types=1), [only answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1816894/markdown-for-posts-by-a-specific-user?userid=8250&types=2) and [both](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1816894/markdown-for-posts-by-a-specific-user?userid=8250&types=1,2).
- A similar query for posts from a deleted user: [only questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1816896/markdown-for-posts-by-a-deleted-user?userid=9072&types=1), [only answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1816896/markdown-for-posts-by-a-deleted-user?userid=9072&types=2) and [both](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1816896/markdown-for-posts-by-a-deleted-user?userid=9072&types=1,2).

I will repeat a few of the usual caveats:

- [SEDE](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/data-explorer/info) is only updated once a week - so you won't get very recent posts.
- You don't get the deleted posts in this way. (There is a table `PostsWithDeleted` which contains *some* data about deleted posts - but neither body nor the post owner. So it cannot be used for the purposes discussed here.)
- The results of a query are limited to 50000 rows - but so far even the most prolific posters on MO are [below 50k posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1580473/users-with-most-posts-questions-answers) (or [50k comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1798655/users-with-most-comments)) - so this won't be problem for MO in the near future.

Naturally, it is possible to do much more - if you have a look at
[rene's answer to "Dump of my own Stack Exchange content"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269951), you can see that there is a query which collects contributions over all sites, creates a HTML file consisting of all results. And also an alternative query, which returns Markdown - again for posts from all sites in the network.